# Where do I need changes to this script to work in Chrome browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome

I use this script in a pdf form. The total field is blank (no zeros) until numbers are input then it adds fields to the total. It works in Adobe Reader and it works using if you open in web browser IE. It does something weird with calculations when opened to fill in using Chrome. This is the script:

```
var v = event.value;
 if (v == 0)
 {
   event.target.display = display.hidden;
 }
 else
 {
   event.target.display = display.visible;
 }
```

Can someone help? Thank you RB

Comment: The path is: event.target.style.display. I do not know the actual origins of v or display, so it is impossible to understand their validity in use.

Comment: First, thank you for responding. Please bear with me, my knowledge is limited. I created a fillable pdf form where you could input data in various fields. As you entered data, it totalled for you in the total box field. That is where the script is. I found the script and it worked. So, I believe "v" is when the person fills in a number and "display" is if the total is 0, you see nothing, else you see the total calculation in the total box.

Comment: This has been resolved. Thanks!

Comment: Alright, the problem was to broad to understand a specific issue you were having. I am glad you found a solution. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Agreed! Just to let you know, after scouring the internet, turns out the problem was not with the script but with using the Chrome browser. Something to do with Chrome not supporting NPAPI. I do appreciate you initially taking the time to help. Again, thank you.